# How to perform service account admin operations(create, list, delete) by using Cloud Function?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, service-accounts

I want to create, list and delete a service account keys using cloud function.

We do have client libraries to perform these operations in python but how can I authenticate a cloud function with associated service account to perform these operations?

Sample code from official documentation is below:

```
import os

from google.oauth2 import service_account
import googleapiclient.discovery

def list_keys(service_account_email):
"""Lists all keys for a service account."""

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    filename=os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'],
    scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'])

service = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
    'iam', 'v1', credentials=credentials)

keys = service.projects().serviceAccounts().keys().list(
    name='projects/-/serviceAccounts/' + service_account_email).execute()

for key in keys['keys']:
    print('Key: ' + key['name'])
```

In this code, I want to use associated service account rather than below snippet.

```
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    filename=os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'],
    scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'])
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When they are run, by default Cloud Functions use the App Engine default service account (`PROJECT_ID@appspot.gserviceaccount.com`), as indicated in the  GCP [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/iam#runtime_service_accounts):

> At runtime, Cloud Functions defaults to using the App Engine default service account (PROJECT_ID@appspot.gserviceaccount.com), which has the Editor role on the project. You can change the roles of this service account to limit or extend the permissions for your running functions. You can also change which service account is used by providing a non-default service account on a per-function basis.

Although, if necessary, you can [provide a non-default service account on a per-function basis](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/function-identity#per-function_identity) (due to the nature of the permissions you require, probably it would be convenient follow this approach and create a specific service account instead of use the default App Engine one).

To use this service account, get rid of the `credentials` parameter when building your service:

```py
service = googleapiclient.discovery.build('iam', 'v1')
```

To perform the required service account management operations, the service account configured for run the Cloud Function must be granted the `roles/iam.serviceAccountAdmin` IAM role. Please, see the relevant [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#service-accounts-roles).

Comment: Thanks for answering, it worked for me. But I am facing one more challenge here that is when I am deleting all the keys. It can't delete system managed key, how can I distinguish system managed key and customer managed key?

Comment: You are welcome Vikash. You can, for example, [get a list](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys) of the different keys associated with a certain service account. As a result, you will obtain a list of [`ServiceAccountKey`](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts.keys#ServiceAccountKey) objects, one for every corresponding service account key. See next comment

Comment: Inspect the `keyOrigin` field, and filter this [enumeration](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts.keys#ServiceAccountKeyOrigin) by the necessary value, `USER_PROVIDED` of `GOOGLE_PROVIDED`, as you need. I hope it helps.