# How to distinguish system managed key and customer managed key in Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, service-accounts, google-iam

I am trying to write a cloud function to delete keys generated for a service account.
But it is not allowing cloud function to delete the system managed key.

How can I distinguish system managed and customer managed key on the fly? So that I can skip if it is a system managed key and delete if it is a customer managed key.

Comment: 1/2) Google does not allow access to the private key for Google managed service account keys. Each service account has one even if not visible. I am not sure how to detect which is which. An idea is to attempt to download the key material (JSON). If denied it is a system managed key (or you do not have permission). If you are permitted then it is a key that was created by an IAM user.

Comment: 2/2) One thing to note. The system managed key is always the first one based upon what I have seen. That makes sense if Google automatically creates the first key when you create the service account. This key is also automatically rotated by Google.

Comment: Thanks @JohnHanley, your response is really helpful to understand IAM. My intent was to know identification of different type of keys programmatically. I have posted an answer which I found in other post :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get to know the answer of this question in my other question's response.

[How to perform service account admin operations(create, list, delete) by using Cloud Function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66117626/how-to-perform-service-account-admin-operationscreate-list-delete-by-using-c)

Credit to [@jccampanero](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13942448/jccampanero)

At a high level, it can be identified by looking at the KeyType [enumeration](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts.keys#KeyType).

- **KEY_TYPE_UNSPECIFIED** Unspecified key type. The presence of this in
  the message will immediately result in an error.
- **USER_MANAGED** User-managed keys (managed and rotated by the user).
- **SYSTEM_MANAGED**   System-managed keys (managed and rotated by Google).

Answer (score 1):

Posting this as a community wiki as it's based on @JohnHanley's comments as those are a valid answer to this question:

Google does not allow access to the private keys for Google managed service account keys. Each service account has one even if not visible. I am not sure how to detect which is which but an idea on how to do it is to attempt to download the key material (JSON).

If denied it is a system managed key (or you do not have permission) and If you are permitted then it is a key that was created by an IAM user.

**Note**: The system managed key is always the first one. That makes sense if Google automatically creates the first key when you create the service account. This key is also automatically rotated by Google.

**[Additional information by John Hanley]**

I do not have a reference link for my comments. I figured this out by observation and writing code. I also have a fairly deep understanding of how IAM and security accounts work at a low level.

A Google Cloud service account consists of an RSA private key. Each private key has a corresponding public key. Google Cloud publishes the public key even for these "private" private keys.

When you create a service account but do not create a key pair, you can still use the service account with Google Cloud services. In my case I used Compute Engine with a new service account. The Google Cloud Metadata server does not provide the private key for a service account. This is one of the reasons for the IAM functions such as SignBlob. You cannot access the private key, but Google Cloud IAM can.

In my testing, I signed data with IAM and then verified that signature with the public key. Therefore, I was able to deduce that a service account with no keys actually has a "private" private key otherwise called the system managed key in the original question.